# Intersection of a dense subset with a closed subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $B,\: D$ be a closed, dense subsets respectively. Assume that $B\cap D\not=\phi$. Is it true that $B\cap D$ is either compact or dense in $B$?

What if we assumed $X, B$ and $D$ to be connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for example
\begin{align*}
X &= [0, 10] \subseteq \Bbb{R} \\
D &= X \cap \Bbb{Q} \\
B &= \{\pi\} \cup [5,10].
\end{align*}
Note that $\pi \notin \overline{B \cap D}$, so $B \cap D$ is not dense in $B$. Also, $\sqrt{30} \in \overline{B \cap D} \setminus (B \cap D)$, hence $B \cap D$ is not closed and hence not compact.

Comment: Thanks, what if we assumed that $B$ and $D$ are connected? I added this to the main question.

Comment: Then the answer is still "no", but you'd have to go to two dimensions. Imagine the union of a closed rectangle, and a vertical line intersecting the rectangle, whose $x$-coordinate is constantly $r$, where $r$ is irrational. Then intersecting this set with $\Bbb{Q}^2$ would produce a set that is neither closed nor dense.